# Why does Scala need the def statement?

Tags: javascript, scala, immutability

I am new to scala, but I have background in javascript.

While I see the need to separate between `val` and `var` (mutable and immutable), I can't see why the `def` statement should ever be needed.

If functions are truly first-class citizens, as in javascript, why should they be declared with `def` and not with `val` ?

Is that design decision based on JVM related constraints, or is there some underlying logic that I fail to comprehend ?

Comment: @0__ not quite the dupe: op asks *why it was designed this way*, not *what is the difference*

Comment: @om-nom-nom: The OP asks why functions are declared with `def`, but functions aren't declared with `def`, they are declared with `=>`, and `def` doesn't declare functions, it declares methods, which are fundamentally different from functions. The whole premise of the question is that methods and functions are the same thing, which is simply wrong, and is nicely explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag *The whole premise of the question is that methods and functions are the same thing, which is simply wrong.* Again, this is *what is the difference* (in other words, they ARE different indeed), but it does not explains why such separation was made many years ago in a first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One big limitation of functions is that they cannot be generic as a value. E.g.

```
def foo[A](bar: A): Unit
```

That cannot be expressed as a function value

```
val foo: A => Unit  // A is _not_ a type parameter
```

that requires a resolution of type parameter `A`. Other differences are: Methods carry a natural notion of `this` as the enclosing class; they can abort via `return`. They can have multiple parameter lists, most importantly an implicit parameter list. They have named and default arguments. (I'm trying to imagine how a function with named and default arguments would look, perhaps it could be designed)

It probably would not have been impossible to just have function values, but `def` seems like a better match for the OO aspects of Scala.

Comment: You should first state the basic difference (`def` is used to declare *methods*, which is quite different from declaring functions). Besides that, this is actually a pretty good answer, and so I don't understand why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

`def` differs from `val` and `var` in that every time the variable is referenced, its expression is reevaluated.

Comment: Exactly. That's the real reason.

Comment: @rsenna Not true. `object Foo { var bar = 1234; val baz = (i: Int) => i + bar }; Foo.bar=5678; Foo.baz(1)`. Functions catch the closure scope just as methods.

Comment: @0__ wat? Even if what you're saying is right (and it is), it does not have any necessary relation to what this answer says.

Comment: @0__ I did not say that you cannot have a `val` which is a closure. That is allowed.

Comment: Both a function value and a method are reevaluated every time you call `apply` or the method.

Comment: @0__ No, the function value _itself_ is not reevaluated; only its `apply` method is. You can see it by changing to `val baz = { println("baz is evaluated"); (i: Int) => i + bar }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's language decision made for easier migration from Java. It's quite a big shift in mind to watch on functions as on function-values.